# Does proxy have to load everything completely first before sending them back?

Tags: apache, http, iis, proxy, http-proxy

I've been using proxy services, and I want to know some details behind it, regarding its speed and efficiency. Consider following scenario:

There's a mp3 file on server M, a client wants to download that file, but he doesn't want to expose himself, so he decides to use a proxy website to download. The get mp3 request is therefore send to proxy server P first, then proxy server would get that mp3 for the client, here's my question about some details:

Does P have to download the entire mp3 file first before it can pass it to the client? If so, the file is downloaded twice (first on proxy server, then on client's machine) , taking about twice amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxies normally operate in two modes: HTTP and Connect.

The Connect mode is for blackbox protocols like HTTPS or ftp. Where most of the data is meaningless octet streams. Because they are encrypted or unstructured files.

However, for HTTP, proxies are pretty smart. One of the things that they do is caching stuff. Like images and web page contents when you are downloading a website in your browser via proxy.Moreover, for octet streams under HTTP, proxies show the connect behavior, meaning that they open a relay socket and let you download the content. In the meanwhile, they will store it locally, and if it doesn't exceed a certain size the file will be also cached.

The files are also forwarded, or relayed, or sometimes called rewrited. This [here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/YouTube) is a sample config file that shows squid configured to forward Youtube videos and not caching them.

Another reason why downloading and forwarding is not an option is doubling the round trip time (RTT). It is really counterintuitive when you add another RTT that slows down a HTTP session.